# iPhone SDK: disabling cllipping for UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm working on an iPhone game, and trying to use a UIScrollView to display some icons, which I then want to enable the user to drag off the bar being scrolled, onto another view (basically, dragging them from their hand into play on the game board).  The problem is that the UIScrollView clips everything outside it's own bounds.

Here is a picture of what I'm trying to do:

[image]

Functionally, it actually works, in that you can drag the icons up to the white board fine...but you can't see them as you are dragging...which is not acceptable.

Does anyone know if you can temporarily disable the clipping that a scroll view does, or is there some way to get around it?  Hacky or not, I would really like to make it happen.

Does anyone have any other possible solutions for this?  Or maybe any alternate approaches?  I've considered if maybe a page view might work, but haven't tried it yet...and it's not at all as good of a solution as the scroll view.

Worst case I can just go back to not having the bar scrollable, but that really puts a damper on some of my game mechanics, and I'm really not too excited about that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're looking for the clipsToBounds property of UIView.  I've used it successfully with UIScrollView:

```
scrollView.clipsToBounds = NO;
```

However, the dragging you want to do from the scroll view to the game view may require you to remove the icon view from the scroll view, place it in the superview at a position corresponding to its visible position within the scroll view (calculated using the scroll view's origin and content offset), and have that track the user's finger movements.  On a release of the touch, either drop it on the game view at the proper position or return it to the scroll view.

Comment: awesome, I was looking for a property like that and couldn't find it for the life of me.  and yes, that's exactly what I am already doing (removing the icon view from one view, then recreating the new one on the board at the correct location).

Comment: So Brad, this works perfectly for the dragging part, thank you!  My new question, can I clip the bar view (not the icon draggable views, but the container view that is a child of the UIScrollView) without clipping the icon views.  I imagine I can't have it both ways, but would like to try. =)

Comment: While you can set clipsToBounds for the scroll view to NO and then YES for the container UIView, if your icons are within the container the net result will be the same as if the scroll view was doing the clipping.  If you're talking about just the bar above the icons, then you'll be good.

Comment: I think I'm just going to have to live with it not clipping, which honestly might be the best user experience anyway.  I was just trying to know all of my options while I had the question open and knowledgeable people to answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure I understand the question but I think you should look into the z order of the scrollview and the whiteboard. It may be that the drag is just going behind the whiteboard.

Failing that, it would be useful to see all the bounds of your view heirarchy.

I also think a better solution allround might be to create a "sprite" to animate underneath the players finger - you could offset the drawpoint of the sprite from the touchlocation so that the player can see what they are dragging.

Comment: Good suggestion on the z-order, I looked into that, and it's not the case.  The child view is clipped in every direction, even where there is no other view to be behind.  The sprite idea is something I briefly considered, I think I will do that if the other suggestion doesn't work.